# tshark doesn't always print source ip

Tags: tshark

How can i get the tcp payload of packets with tshark, and also get the source IP that sent these packets?

This command works for most packets, but some packets are still printed WITHOUT a source IP (Why?) :

```
tshark -Y "tcp.dstport == 80" -T fields -d tcp.port==80,echo -e echo.data -e ip.src
```

*To test my command, run it and then browse to http://stackoverflow.com. Notice that usually the data chunks ("47:45:54:20:2f:61:64:73:...") have an IP after them, but not always.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem:
The packets with a missing source IP were IPv6, but my original command only prints IPv4.

This works:

```
tshark -Y "tcp.dstport == 80" -T fields -d tcp.port==80,echo -e echo.data -e ip.src -e ipv6.src
```